# Deleting object in hierarchy only removes top level object?

Tags: 3d-view

Trying to import animation fbx but that also imports another one of my character model. So of course I go to delete it in hierarchy view, easy enough. Right click, delete. Instead of deleting the parent object and all its children like I'd expect it to, it deletes the parent object and unparents the children so they remain in my hierarchy.

So my scene looks like this:

- CharacterObject

then after right clicking that object and selecting delete:

- CharacterBody
- RootBone

Whoever was in charge of designing this deserves a flick on the nose... I googled all the ways of asking about this I could think of and couldn't find anything except instructions that seem to do nothing.

Is there an obvious way to delete an object in the scene that I don't see? Or Even better, a way to import an animation without importing the character object with it?

Comment: Your picture link is broken.
Try using "Delete Hierarchy" from the right-click menu in the Outliner instead.

Comment: There wasn't any picture, this site just ignores my formatting for some reason.
I am actually referring to the Outliner when I say Hierarchy view. I've just never heard that terminology for it up until this point.
There is no "Delete Hierarchy" option in the right click menu.

Comment: What version are you using?
Somebody else said that the other day, I have checked in version 2.80, 2.82, 2.83 2.90 and 2.91 and it is there in all versions for me. I am running Linux versions, perhaps this is a Windows version bug? Try the latest version if you haven't already.

Comment: delete hierarchy exists in 2.92 for Windows

Comment: I'm currently on windows 2.81a version so I'll try updating! It's crazy that this isn't the default functionality though. Do any of you know why that is?